# What makes an “explain this” question appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion

We have recently seen a significant number of questions that contain significant quotes from external sources and often very little other content. Some of these [were mentioned a while ago](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/user-with-a-flood-of-questions) and it wasn't clear that any action was warranted. However the overall volume is now at a level that we as moderators feel is not good for the site’s signal/noise ratio. After all, the goal of Stack Exchange is to build a [high-quality question and answer library](https://stackexchange.com/tour).

We already have [guidelines for referencing in answers](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), but none for questions. As a community, what do we think would make these questions asking for explanations of external sources appropriate for the site?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my view, questions should be subject to the same [referencing guidelines as for answers](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), most importantly:

> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their
>   words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to
>   the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link
>   to it.

Formulate your own independent question based on the material. Don’t simply say “explain this” or similar.

For example if you don’t understand something, state what you don’t understand and what are the possible interpretations you’ve thought of.

Comment: I agree with this - and to the extent any question is 'close' to being answerable, the person who wants to answer that question should edit the question to make it so.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I'm surprised you "agree with this". Doesn't this contradict your comments https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/117259/why-does-crystallizing-your-lifetime-capital-gains-exemption-increase-share-acb#comment239272_117259 and https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/121230/whats-corporate-paid-up-capital#comment239273_121230?

Comment: @MelissaYueWallace Yes after reading this question and answer, I've been convinced otherwise. If you edit your questions to indicate more concretely how the very technical material impacts your tax situation it would make an answer relevant for this site.

Answer (score -6):

GS's answer  is too restrictive and doesn't appear good faith. GS has closed unilaterally too many questions and deleted too many answers based on external source, even if that source answers the question.

> Formulate your own independent question based on the material. Don’t simply say “explain this” or similar.
>
> For example if you don’t understand something, state what you don’t understand and what are the possible interpretations you’ve thought of.

Pls see my questions below. I quoted material, and stated "what you don’t understand". I don't understand the material, so how the heck can I state "what are the possible interpretations you’ve thought of"??? How can I f"ormulate your own independent question based on the material"?

[Why does crystallizing your lifetime capital gains exemption increase share ACB?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/117259)

https://money.stackexchange.com/q/121230

In both Grade 'Eh' Bacon munificently agrees they are "answerable question, and relevant to a small business owner in Canada".

Also, if a reliable quote can answer it, writing your answer from scratch

1. wastes time and is useless.
2. is less reliable.